# getting value from the loop to store in array

Tags: ios

I have this code from which i am checking songs that are present in my app and storing the number of songs in an NSMUTABLEArray but there is something wrong it always shows null

```
    for (int i = 1; i < 100; ++i) {
    // Load the plist
    NSString *plist = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i] ofType:@"mp3"];
    if (nil == plist) {
        NSLog(@"not found (%i)", i);
        continue;
    }




    NSLog(@"Found Songs (%i)",i);

    [MYNSMUTABLEArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];

    NSLog(@"%@",MYNSMUTABLEArray);
```

}

the i variable is working absolutely fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create your mutable array, so that an object exists to store the data. I presume that the code at the moment is sending the `addObject:` message to `nil`.

I'd strongly suggest a better variable name than `MYNSMUTABLEArray`, so here is my code snippit that should go **before** the loop.

```
NSMutableArray* myMutableArray = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Then where you are adding the object, you'd use:

```
[myMutableArray addObject:@(i)];
```

*Bootnote:* A little tip, you can use `@` literals to automatically box your primitive `int` value into an `NSNumber` object. This is used in the `addObject:` example, and is in the form `@(int)`.